# recyclerView is Crashed when list items add after clear while scroll recyclerView in android

Tags: android, exception, android-recyclerview

i'm android developer.

my service use recyclerView in googleMap layout.
many marker place in google map.

recyclerView layout is up animation on googleMap when marker click in map.
figure out crash situation

other marker click (load recyclerView items and add items in adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged) when recyclerView is scrolling (not end scrolling, recyclerView state is not idle state)
occurred exception and crash my app

exception stack trace

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{5d40055 position=17 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5297)
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5479)
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1325)
                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1061)
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4726)
                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:635)
                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

searched in stack over flow use google search.

but i can't find solution.

tried solutions.

- create custom LinearLayoutManager and @override supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() method return false
- recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear() before adapter.addItems
- many more ways

this issue is RecyclerView itself bug?
please answer please thanks! have a good day

## **---------below my code-------**

**activity**

```
Retrofit2.getApiClient().someApi(
                id,
                name
).enqueue(new CustomCallBack<ResultObject>(){
    @Override
    public void SuccessResponse(Object response){
        List<Object> tempArr = response.data();
        mAdapter.addItems(tempArr);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**adapter**

```
List<Object> mData;

public void addItems(List<IArticleInterface> list) {
        mData.addAll(list);
}
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: @AntonisLat added code now, help me plz thanks

Comment: did you get any solutions>